# python integer overflow solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer-overflow

I am fairly new to Python and am currently creating a "RSA Encryption" program to send Secret messages to peers. I have the program completed, but run into issues with computations. I keep getting an overflow error because the numbers I am trying to crunch are too large for native python. Unassigned 256 bit numbers would be my ideal case, however I am having issues finding a library that supports them.I have also read that you can compress numbers into a more manageable format, however I have no direction or thought on how to do that.

If you have any proposed solutions to my issue It would be greatly appreciated! thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Python supports arbitrary precision integers natively:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 18:20:46) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180317 (Red Hat 8.0.1-0.19)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2**256
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
>>> 2**512
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096
```

But when you use some number crunching frameworks, like for example NumPy, then [it will use platform native integers](http://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html), which are limited usually to 64 bits.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! the number i'm looking at right now is closer to 223^4493, I may need to rethink how this encryption system works, because this number seems absurdly large. and this is the case when my prime numbers i use to generate the key are only double digits. if i wanted prime numbers with 4 or 5 digits the number would get.... to large.